# Logical approach of a simple combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> Consider all functions f:{1,2,3,4}→{1,2,3,4} which are one-one, onto
> and satisfy the following property: if f(k)is odd then f(k+1)is even,
> k =1,2,3. Then, number of such functions

So this is how I solved the problem

If o denoted odd and e denotes even then,
the possibilities of the **range of f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4) respectively** based on the specified conditions including k=4 will be

1. o e o e } First o which is for f(1) can take either 1 or 3 and the first e which is for f(2) can take 2 or 4. So we totally have $2*^2C_1$ selections = 4
2. e o e o } Similarly 4 combinations here if f(1) starts with even value
3. o e e o } Similarly 4 here too

Therefore $4*3=12$ Possibilities.
My math textbook says 12 as well. But is my approach correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: THANKS THREAD CLOSED

Comment: @RobPratt Not exactly but indeed helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative: there are $4!=24$ one-to-one mappings. Of these, some don’t fulfill the property i.e. some have consecutive o, $2\times 3!=12$ of them. $24-12=12$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach and answer is correct